# Как сделать длину строки равной переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

В моем коде необходимо длину строки сделать равной значению хранящемуся в переменной типа int.
Например:

```
("{:^45}".format(t))
```

Вот тут вместо `45` нужен условно `x`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5):

Вложите скобки. Они обрабатываются рекурсивно:

```
@>>> w = 20
@>>> t = '0123456789'
@>>> '{:^{}}'.format(t, w)
'     0123456789     '
```

Более современный способ через [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings). Идея та же:

```
@>>> w = 20
@>>> t = '0123456789'
@>>> f'{t:^{w}}'
'     0123456789     '
```

Answer (score 0):

Для полноты картины предложу ещё вариант форматирования в стиле printf. И хотя он уступает по возможностям новым способам форматирования строк, думаю, кому-нибудь может быть полезен.

Чтобы printf читал ширину строки из своих параметров, надо указать специальный символ `*`.

```
>>> '%*s' % (12, 'abc')
'         abc'
```

К сожалению, выравнивание строк по центру не поддерживается. Возможно только выравнивание по правому краю (по умолчанию) или по левому (с помощью минуса: `'%-*s'`).

Полное описание форматирующих строк есть в документации:
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting