# Как при форматировании строки установить переменное значение точности для вещественных чисел?

Tags: python

Собственно в заголовке весь вопрос уже полностью дан, но повторю его. Как в ('%.3f' % i) где i это число, заменить 3 перед f на число в переменной?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать длину строки равной переменной?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1287443/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте f-строки:

```
i = 1/3
p = 5
res = f'{i:.{p}f}'  # '0.33333'
```

Answer (score 0):

Через обычный str.format() тоже можно подставить переменную.

```
i = 5    
print('%.{}f'.format(i))
```

Либо, если нужно сразу вывести в строку результат, а не подготовить, к примеру, шаблон, то можно так:

```
value = 0.1
precision_count = 4
print('{0:.{1}f}'.format(value, precision_count)) # 0.1000
```

Comment: Вопрос в том, как установить количество знаков после точки через переменную

Comment: В тексте после: Как в ('%.3f' % i) где i это число, заменить 3 перед f на число в переменной?