# Вывод числа с плавающей точкой с точностью, заданной переменной

Tags: python, float, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Надо вывести число с точностью, заданной переменной

```
num = 12.123456789
n = 3
```

Out:

```
12.123
```

Встречала такое решение:

```
print("%.3f" % num)
```

Но там точность указывается непосредственно, как указывать при помощи значения переменной?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса:[Как при форматировании строки установить переменное значение точности для вещественных чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1296758/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num = 12.123456789
f = 3
print("{:.{}f}".format(num, f))
```